# From where does a VPN connection start encryption of traffic?

Tags: vpn

I have a VPN with vpn,sh in a home network and I would like to know at which nodes the tunnel starts and ends for example is the traffic being sent from my computer encrypted before it reaches my router or is it encrypted when it reaches my ISP before leaving for the internet?

Comment: VPN is end to end encryption. Your isp sees nothing but garbled data.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure that vpn,sh has any meaning, but a VPN encrypts data between the tunnel endpoints - thus if you are running the VPN client on your computer, everything between your computer and the far end of the tunnel is encrypted (ie your router will only see the encrypted traffic).

Similarly, if you have the VPN set up on your router, traffic between your computer and router can be sniffed, and if your ISP can log in to your router they could possibly see the traffic - however failing that they will see the encrypted data on their network.

(If your ISP is claiming to running a VPN, you can ignore that claim as far as any security benefit goes for you.)